# Parsing the full input twice

Tags: f#, fparsec

To achieve case-insensitive infix operators using `OperatorPrecedenceParser`, I'm preprocessing the input, parsing it as text delimited by string literals. The text portion is then searched for infix operators that need to be uppercased (to conform to the operator as known to the `OPP`). The actual parsing then takes place.

My question is, can both phases be combined into a single parser? I tried

```ml
// preprocess: Parser<string,_>
// scalarExpr: Parser<ScalarExpr,_>
let filter = (preprocess .>> eof) >>. (scalarExpr .>> eof)
```

but it fails at the end of the input, seemingly expecting a `scalarExpr`. The input can be parsed by `preprocess` and `scalarExpr` independently, so I'm guessing it's an issue with `eof`, but I can't seem to get it right. Is this possible?

Here are the other parsers for reference.

```
let stringLiteral = 
  let subString = manySatisfy ((<>) '"')
  let escapedQuote = stringReturn "\"\"" "\""
  (between (pstring "\"") (pstring "\"") (stringsSepBy subString escapedQuote)) 

let canonicalizeKeywords =
  let keywords = 
    [
      "OR"
      "AND"
      "CONTAINS"
      "STARTSWITH"
      "ENDSWITH"
    ]
  let caseInsensitiveKeywords = HashSet(keywords, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
  fun text ->
    let re = Regex(@"([\w][\w']*\w)")
    re.Replace(text, MatchEvaluator(fun m ->
      if caseInsensitiveKeywords.Contains(m.Value) then m.Value.ToUpperInvariant()
      else m.Value))

let preprocess = 
  stringsSepBy 
    ((manySatisfy ((<>) '"')) |>> canonicalizeKeywords) 
    (stringLiteral |>> (fun s -> "\"" + s + "\""))
```

Comment: Are your operators so long, that you can't just add all the case combinations you're interested in to the OPP (e.g. using a little helper function)? How do you uppercase the operators during preprocessing, do you directly mutate the input buffer? If you want to parse the input twice, you have to backtrack to the beginning or create a new CharStream.

Comment: There are five such operators (maybe more in the future), the longest being 10 chars. `preprocess` returns a new string with the uppercased operators.

Comment: I've updated my question with the other parsers. I just realized I probably need `>>=` instead of `>>.` but the types don't work out, so I'm stumped at the moment.

Comment: @StephanTolksdorf: Is it safe to say I need to call `parse` twice, once for each parser? No way to combine them?

Comment: If I read this correctly, `preprocess` is a parser that returns the preprocessed string. If that is correct, you need to create a new CharStream for this string and run the second parser on this CharStream, e.g. by using runParserOnString. However, the whole approach is pretty ugly. Could you maybe get away with just supporting the sane case combinations, i.e. lowercase, UPPERCASE, camelCase and PascalCase?

Comment: This is a language for end-users to express database query filters, so, I somewhat expect case-sensitivity to trip them up. I agree that it's ugly.

Comment: Instead of transforming the input, you could also do a simple case invariant search for all occurrences of the keywords in the input, and then add OPP entries for all case combinations you find (which probably aren't many). This initial search doesn't have to be precise, because adding a superset of the required case combinations isn't a problem.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, but it still requires pre-parsing the string to avoid operators within literals, right, e.g., "or" in "liberty or death"?

Comment: If the initial search finds too many keywords, e.g. in literals, that shouldn't be a problem for the later parsing, because in the worst case you just add some superfluous case combinations to the OPP. This assumes you have a fixed set of operators, e.g. the five from your sample.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable (and much cleaner) approach. I'd you'd like to post that as an answer I'll accept. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to parse case insensitive operators with FParsec's [OperatorPrecedenceParser](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/operatorprecedenceparser.html) is to add operator definitions for every casing you want to support. If you only need to support short operator names, such as "and" or "or", you could simply add all possible case combinations. If you want to use operator names that are too long for this approach, you might consider only supporting the sane casings, i.e. lowercase, UPPERCASE, camelCase and PascalCase. When you want to support multiple casings, it is usually convenient to write a helper function that automatically generates all the needed casings for you from a standard one.

If you have long operator names and you really want to support all casings, the `OperatorPrecedenceParser`'s dynamic configurability also allows the following approach, which  should be easier and more efficient than transforming the input:

1. Search the input for all case insensitive occurrences of the supported operators. This search shouldn't miss any occurrences, but it's no problem if it finds false positives if e.g. the operator name is used inside a function name or inside a string literal.
2. Add all unique casings you found in step 1 to the `OperatorPrecedenceParser`. (Usually there won't be many casings of the same operator.)
3. Parse the input with the configured `OperatorPrecedenceParser`.

When you parse multiple inputs, you can keep the `OperatorPrecedenceParser` instance around and just lazily add new operators casings as you need them.